# How to make an API call that requires info from another API call onSubmit React

Tags: reactjs, api, redux

I have a react project involving PokeAPI when a user inputs a Pokemon and hits the submit button I want it to get the Pokemon info from the API and the type info(s) the pokemon has from the API with it. Basically I want to make an api call that requires data from another api call and I want to do this onSubmit.

Right now I have it get the Pokemon info onSubmit and in a different component after the submit have it get the type info but the way I've done it has the component re-rendering indefinitely and I put on a band-aid fix which I'd really like to avoid.

```
function handleSubmit(dispatch) {
  return (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const pokemonNameID = new FormData(event.currentTarget).get('pokemon');
    console.log(pokemonNameID);
    api.getPokemon(pokemonNameID)
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'SELECTED_POKEMON',
          payload: {
            pokemon: response.body,
          }
        })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

```
  return (
    <form action="" onSubmit={handleSubmit(props.dispatch)}>
      <input className="search" type="text" placeholder="name/id" name="pokemon"/>
      <input className="pkmn-button"type="submit"name="."value="."/>
    </form>
  )
}
Search.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func,
}

export default connect(null)(Search);
```

```
class PokemonTypes extends Component {
    shouldUpdate = true;
    count = 0;
    shouldComponentUpdate(){
        if(this.shouldUpdate){
            return true;
        }
        this.count=0;
        this.shouldUpdate = true;
        return false;
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        var typeOne=this.props.pokemon.get("types").get(0).get("type").get("name");
        var typeTwo=typeTwoExists(this.props.pokemon);
        var dispatch = this.props.dispatch;
        api.getType1(typeOne)
        .then((response) => {
            dispatch({
              type: 'POKEMON_TYPE1',
              payload: {
                type1: response.body,
              }
            })
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
        try{
            api.getType2(typeTwo)
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch({
                  type: 'POKEMON_TYPE2',
                  payload: {
                    type2: response.body,
                  }
                })
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
              });
        }catch(e){
            
        }
          this.count+=1;
          if (this.count%2===0){
              this.shouldUpdate = false;
          }
    }
    render() {
        var typeOne=this.props.type1.get("name");
        //this.props.pokemon.get("types").get(0).get("type").get("name");
        var typeTwo=typeTwoExists(this.props.pokemon);
        return (
            <div>
                <IsPokemonTypes type1={typeOne}
                type2={typeTwo} />
             </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PokemonTypes);
```

How can I make all the api calls onSubmit when they require info from another API call that is also called onSubmit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, first we make the call to fetch the Pokemon, then once we get the Pokemon data, we make another two calls to get the types?  I don't love that the two types are duplicated versions of essentially the same code but that's not what you're asking.

In my opinion the best way to handle the second API call is by conditionally rendering a second component which initiates loading the types.  You would have a parent component which handles loading the Pokemon data and also selecting it from state.  Once that component sees that the data is loaded in the state, then it renders the type loading component, passing in props which were set in the state from the first API call.  The type loading component will execute the second API call as soon as it is mounted.

**Edit:**

The second response doesn't depend on the entirety of the first response, it just depends on one little snippet of data from the first response (the type names/ids).  So we want to abstract this out into a `Type` component that takes a prop `name` only.

As far as having one component which both fetches and renders vs separate components for fetching and rendering, the main consideration is whether you want to reuse the same fetch logic with multiple different display formats on different page of your app.  When you get more advanced you probably want to break it out, but for now our component will both fetch and render.

When you dispatch a type to redux, we don't want this action to be tied to the specific pokemon.  Instead of `type: 'POKEMON_TYPE1'` it should be `type: 'RECEIVE_TYPE'`.  We'll store the types to a separate section of the state. When you are accessing the types for a specific pokemon, you would use a redux selector to select the type names from the pokemon object, and then you would select the type data from the types state section.  Which actually makes it pretty easy to avoid duplicated type calls, now that I think about it.  We pass in the type name (always a defined `string`) and the type data (maybe a complete response or maybe `undefined`) and we only need to initiate the fetch if data is `undefined`.

By the way, since you're just learning I would recommend that you learn with function components and hooks rather than class components and `connect(mapStateToProps)`.  You're doing the older way, which does still work, but why not learn the newer way?

This is incomplete pseudo-code and will require changes and tweaks.

```
class Type extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        if ( ! this.props.data ) {
            api.getType(this.props.name)
                .then((response) => {
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'RECEIVE_TYPE',
                        payload: {
                            name: this.props.name,
                            data: response.body,
                        }
                    })
                })
        } 
    }

    render() {
        <div>
        {this.props.data ? (
            <>{/** your render goes here */}</>
        ) : (
            <LoadingSpinner />
        )}
        </div>
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, {name}) => {
    return {
        data: state.types[name],
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Type)
```

`name` is a regular prop which is provided directly.  `data` comes from a selector that looks for type data based on the `name` prop. Since our component is connected, after the `dispatch` is sent from `componentDidMount`, `this.props.data` should become defined.

The `PokemonTypes` component, which takes a pokemon object as a prop, is reduced to almost nothing by passing all the work off to our `Type` component.

```
class PokemonTypes extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.pokemon.types.map( typeObject => (
                    <Type name={typeObject.type.name}/>
                ) )}
             </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I don't know how your custom pokemon object works, so that `map` is based off the data format of the API response.  Notice that we don't have to deal with `typeOne` and `typeTwo` separately when we handle it as an array of types.  If we wanted to render the two types differently, we could pass `slot` as a prop to `Type`.

```
{this.props.pokemon.types.map(typeObject => (
    <Type
        name={typeObject.type.name}
        slot={typeObject.slot}
    />
))}
```

Comment: Yes once the api call is made for the pokemon I want to immediately make another api call to get the 1 or 2 types infos the pokemon has. I am a bit new to all this so let me make sure I understand right, I pass the pokemon info into another component like this <pokemonType pokemon = {this.props.pokemon} /> and then in the pokemonType component with componentDidMount make the api calls for the types? Or are you saying make a new component that handles loading specifically?

Comment: The first one is what I was suggesting (`<pokemonType pokemon = {this.props.pokemon} /> `).  But thinking about what I know about pokemon, the response from the type doesn't actually depend on the specific pokemon, right?  Like "electric" is the same response whether it's from a Pickachu or a Magnemite.  So the prop for a `Type` component should be the *type name* rather than the pokemon object.  I'll update my answer with some pseudo-code.

Comment: By the way, I don't know the implementation details of this custom object that you've created `this.props.pokemon.get("types").get(0).get("type").get("name");`  I assume you're doing that as a way to ensure that properties exist instead of just accessing them directly and potentially having errors.  I used to to things like this, but then I started using [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html) and I would never look back!